# imap.gmail.com returning self signed certificate with Alpine

Tags: email, gmail, imap, alpine-linux

I am setting up Alpine for Gmail and followed the steps from 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/130899/how-can-i-configure-alpine-to-read-my-gmail-in-ubuntu

I entered the field as `Server: imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/user=<me>@gmail.com` and it shows me the error message as pasted below

Also I can't find any info on why this should not work? Should imap.gmail.com be returning a self signed certificate? I don't have 2FA enabled on gmail.

I am on Alpine 2.21.99

Error message:

```
There was a failure validating the SSL/TLS certificate for the server

                                   imap.gmail.com

    The reason for the failure was

                         self signed certificate (details)
```

Comment: Likely your Admin is using an MITM box to sniff SSL connections.  Is this in your workplace?  Or Alpine can't find your certificate store.  Either way, this question should be on our sister site superuser or unix since this question is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need to add the "no validate" option, like this:

```
{imap.gmail.com/ssl/NoValidate-Cert/user=sergey@gmail.com}
```

I have tried it and it works, but the idea is [not mine](https://superuser.com/a/430386/1088837)